# Difference between is_page and is_page_template

Tags: theme-development

I have been studying **WordPress** theme developer handbook. And I got stuck understanding the difference between `is_page` and `is_page_templates`. Can someone help me to get a clear understanding easily?

Answer (score 7):

`is_page()` returns true if the main query is for a single Page. If you provide an argument, which can be an ID, slug, or title, it will only return true if the main query is for the *specific* page with that ID, slug, or title.

`is_page_template()` returns true if you are viewing a page that has the given [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

So `is_page_template( 'template-about.php' );` will return true if you are viewing a page that is using the custom template `template-about.php`. While `is_page( 'about' )` will only return true of you are viewing a page with the slug `about`.

Regarding when I say 'the main query', whenever you visit a URL in WordPress there will be a query for the content for that URL. So on http://example.com/about the main query will be for the page `about`, while on http://example.com/category/tutorials the main query will be for posts in the `tutorials` category. So `is_page()` is checking what the main thing being queried is.

Answer (score 4):

The WordPress function [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) is used to determine if the user is on a page assigned to a specified page template.

I use it often when I enqueue styles and scripts, like so:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/flex-page.php' ) ) {
     wp_enqueue_script( 
        'event-move', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.event.move.js', 
        array('jquery'), 
        '01-22-2018', 
        true 
    ); 
}
```

The WordPress function [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) is more specific : it asks if the user is on a specific (singular) page. The parameters that can be passed to the function is usually the page id, but can be page ID, title, slug or array.